# фокус на Tab JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Есть TabPane, в котором вложены несколько панелей Tab. Надо написать метод, который будет принимать имя панели и переводить фокус на эту панель (делать её активной), имя которой передали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом простом случае вам надо обойти все табы, найти нужную и для `TabPane` вызвать метод `select`

```
 tabPane.getTabs()
    .stream()
    .filter(tab ->  tab.getText().equals("myTabName")) // myTabName - необходимое имя табы.
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(tabPane.getSelectionModel::select);
```